# How to separate Thymeleaf front-end from Spring boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm New to The Spring Boot. I have created Spring Boot and Thymeleaf project. I want to separate it to two project as front-end and back-end. Can someone direct me a path.

Comment: Thymeleaf is server rendered, it’s not front end. You directly reference the model that you produce in the controller during template rendering - so how could you separate it?

Comment: what you are talking about is called HTML. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

`Thymeleaf is a modern server-side Java template engine`, it's not supposed to work alone as a front-end project. You should consider any js framework such as Angular/React/Vue to serve as client-side and spring boot for rest api.